# Syntax error with creating a popup in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple pop up using React. In other words, when a user clicks on a button, a simple pop up should appear. However, with my current implementation I am getting a syntax error and I am unsure why. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my main file, where my mock_modal is called, e.g. where my popup is called

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
...

class Calendar extends React.Component {

  ...
  
  mockModalClick () {

  }

  hoverCustomSlot() {
    this.setState({ hoverCustomSlot: !this.state.hoverCustomSlot });
  }

  render() {
    const description = this.state.hoverCustomSlot ?
      (<h4 className="custom-instructions">
        Click, drag, and release to create your custom event
      </h4>)
      : null;

    const addMockModal = this.props.registrarSupported ? (
      <div className="cal-btn-wrapper">
        <button
          type="submit"
          form="form1"
          className="save-timetable add-button"
          data-for="sis-btn-tooltip"
          data-tip
          onClick={this.state.seen ? <MockModal toggle={this.togglePop} /> : null}
        >
          <img src="/static/img/star.png" alt="SIS" style={{ marginTop: '2px' }} />
        </button>
        <ReactTooltip
          id="sis-btn-tooltip"
          class="tooltip"
          type="dark"
          place="bottom"
          effect="solid"
        >
          <span>See my Mock Modal!</span>
        </ReactTooltip>
      </div>
    ) : null;
```

Here is the definition of my pop up

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class PopUp extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.toggle();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="modal_content">
          <span className="close" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            &times;
          </span>
          <form>
            <h3>Register!</h3>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input type="text" name="name" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have added ellipses and did not include other unnecessary code. The exact error that I am getting is:

ERROR in ./static/js/redux/ui/modals/mock_modal.jsx
web_1       | Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:14)

```
 export default class PopUp extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.toggle();
```

Comment: Did you check if your project supports the class properties proposal: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `const` in front of `handleClick`.